# Populating list property in ctor based on other property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model

My application is basically just a survey with questions and multiple choice answers. Questions have Answers, but a specific Answer may lead to a specific Question being asked which might otherwise not be asked at all. e.g. "Do you like chocolate?" (if yes ask...) "Do you prefer German or Dutch chocolate?"

In the Answer class, I am trying to populate a list property "DependentQuestions" which is meant to contain id numbers for the Quesiton(s) that will be asked next if this Answer is chosen. The problem is, I am always getting nothing and I'm not sure why. I confirmed the Answer.id is zero at the time the constructor runs by populating DependentQuestions with the commented code you'll see below.

Each Question has an icollection of Answers.

Question class:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string question { get; set; }

    public int? DependentAnswer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Answer> answers { get; set; }

}
```

Answer class:

```
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string answer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int questionId { get; set; }

    public List<int> DependentQuestions { get; set; }

    public Answer()
    {
        DependentQuestions = new List<int>();
        using (dbSurvey db = new dbSurvey())
        {
            var _list = db.Questions.Where(q => q.DependentAnswer == id).Select(q => q.id).ToList();
            if (_list.Any())
            {
                DependentQuestions.AddRange(_list);
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    DependentQuestions.Add(id);
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

The "answers" collection of the Question class is being filled with the Answers to the given Question and that works just fine, but the DependentQuestions list in the Answer class is always coming up empty since Answer.id is always zero at that point. So why is Answer.id always 0, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Ctor code is run before any property could be set, so how do you expect it to be non-zero? Also, you could have a lazy property, but I am not sure how common it is in EF (you are using EF, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor code is run before any property values are set, so at the point of executing the constructor all properties just contain their default values. That is why it is always 0.

I am not sure what are you using as a data access framework, but generally you can do few things:

1. Create Answer entity with id, so you always have it in constructor:

   ```
   public Answer(int id)
   ```
2. If that's not an option, you could also have a lazy property loading questions as needed:

   ```
   class Answer
   {
       private List<int> _dependentQuestions;
       public List<int> DependentQuestions
       {
           get
           {
               if (_dependentQuestions == null)
                   // load questions here

               return _dependentQuestions;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that this assumes id is already set, you probably should validate that too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suspected as much about the constructor code, but wasn't sure and wasn't sure how to find the answer. The Answer entities are being created when the Question entity is created. I did as you recommended #2. Now I'm getting "Object reference not set ..." which implies to me that it worked! I'm not sure why I'm getting that error though since the code generating it is the very code trying to verify whether it exists or not... I think that's probably a new post, but here's the line causing it (in razor view): `@if (answer.DependentQuestions != null) {`